# wildcards in directory path for transferring the files from source to destination using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have to fetch the files from SFTP account from directory "/sourcedir/Test/TRANS*/*transferfiles*.csv" using PUTTY and transfer them over to my local destination dir. Having trouble using the wildcard "TRANS*" in the directory path. How do i use multiple wildcards in the directory path?? I'm getting the error `"/sourcedir/Test/TRANS*/*transferfiles*.csv": multiple-level wildcards unsupported."`.
TIA

`[string]$TransferResults = & 'C:\Program Files\PuTTY\pscp.exe' -l 'username' -pw 'password' "username@$(IPaddress):/sourcedir/Test/TRANS*/*transferfiles*.csv" $Destination`

I tried the solution that @Cpt.Whale suggested.
Output:

```
Listing directory /sourcedir/Test/                                                                                 drwxr--r--   1        -        -        0 Apr 28 14:43 TRANS_whiteplain         drwxr--r--   1        -        -        0 Apr 28 14:43 TRANS_test_1
```

Code snippet to parse in foreach loop.

```
 foreach($file in $parsedfolders){
    [string]$fpath = $file.fullName
    [string]$TransferResults = & 'C:\Program Files\PuTTY\pscp.exe' -l 'username' -pw 'password' "username@$(IPaddress):$fpath/*transferfiles*.csv" 
$Destination
```

i get the error : unable to identify /*transferfiles*.csv: no such file or directory

Comment: The wildcard would work in the PowerShell command, `Get-Item` but this appears to be a parameter you're passing in without actually getting the results

Comment: Please edit your post to include any error message. If there is no error message, please include the output and what you expect instead, so we have something to work with.

Comment: I'm sorry, i edited the post now. Thanks.

Comment: you're going to have to either get the possible paths before you move the files or `Test-Path` while moving them.

Comment: Depending on the server, you may still be able to use glob strings that don't require a full wildcard like `/TRANS[0-9]/*transferfiles?.csv`

Comment: You'll probably need to list the folders in `/sourcedir/Test/` first with `pscp -ls` like `$folders = pscp [options] -ls [user@]host:/sourcedir/Test/`. Then parse the folder names from there, and do something like `foreach ($folder in $parsedfolders) { pscp.exe "username@$(IPaddress):/sourcedir/Test/$folder/*transferfiles*.csv" }`

Comment: I think i got the first part output: ```Listing directory /sourcedir/Test/
drwxr--r--   1        -        -        0 Apr 28 14:43 TRANS_whiteplain
drwxr--r--   1        -        -        0 Apr 28 14:43 TRANS_test_1```  however when i try to parse the folder name in foreach loop ```/sourcedir/Test/$folder/*transferfiles*.csv``` i get error```pscp.exe : unable to identify /sourcedir/Test/Listing directory /sourcedir/Test: no such file or directory```

Comment: @Razz try and add the example output from `pscp.exe -ls` to your question as a code block instead. The default output that starts with "Listing directory..." can't just be used as-is

Comment: output of the `Listing directory /sourcedir/Test/
                                                                       
        drwxr--r--   1        -        -        0 Apr 28 14:43 TRANS_whiteplain
        drwxr--r--   1        -        -        0 Apr 28 14:43 TRANS_test_1`

Comment: @Cpt.Whale Pls help..I'm trying to convert the output to the below fullname. It still says even though i have the matching file in the directory. ```unable to identify /*transferfiles*.csv: no such file or directory```
```foreach($file in $parsedfolders)
         {
         [string]$fpath = $file.fullName
 [string]$TransferResults = & 'C:\Program Files\PuTTY\pscp.exe' -l 'username' -pw 'password' "username@$(IPaddress):$fpath/*transferfiles*.csv" $Destination```

Comment: @Razz please edit your question to add the output. Comments are very difficult to read, and don't include line breaks

Comment: @Cpt.Whale sorry about that. I've updated the code in my main question. Hope you can help me.

Comment: You could always install powershell over ssh on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume your output from `pscp -ls` looks like this, based on your comment:

```text
Listing directory /sourcedir/Test/                                                                                 
drwxr--r--   1        -        -        0 Apr 28 14:43 TRANS_whiteplain         
drwxr--r--   1        -        -        0 Apr 28 14:43 TRANS_test_1
drwxr--r--   1        -        -        0 Apr 28 14:43 TRANS test spaces
```

From that output, we can use regex to get the folder names:

```
# First, list the folder names in the upper level folder
$folders = & 'C:\Program Files\PuTTY\pscp.exe' -l 'username' -pw 'password' -ls "username@10.0.0.1:/sourcedir/Test/"

# only lines starting with d, select everything after time "0:00"
$pattern = '^d.+\d:\d{2} (.*)' 

# parse output into folder names using regex
$parsedFolders = foreach ($folder in $folders) {
  # trim whitespace
  [regex]::Match($folder,$pattern).Groups[1].Value.trim() |
    # discard empty results
    Where { -not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_) }
}
```

Now the parsed folders should be usable:

```
$parsedFolders

TRANS_whiteplain
TRANS_test_1
TRANS test spaces
```

So try and do your copy for each folder:

```
# Finally, copy files from each parsed folder to destination
$results = foreach ($parsedFolder in $parsedFolders) {
  & 'C:\Program Files\PuTTY\pscp.exe' -l 'username' -pw 'password' "username@10.0.0.1:/sourcedir/Test/$parsedfolder/*transferfiles*.csv" $Destination 
}
```